# Register Firebase Storage as Filesystem in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to register Firebase Storage as filesystem in Laravel application. The issue I have is that I can't find a way to register FirebaseServiceProvider. For ex. this is how I registered Dropbox as a filesystem

```
Storage::extend('dropbox', function (Application $app, array $config) {
            $adapter = new DropboxAdapter(new DropboxClient(
                $config['authorization_token']
            ));
 
            return new FilesystemAdapter(
                new Filesystem($adapter, $config),
                $adapter,
                $config
            );
        });
```

I don't know what to use instead of DropboxAdapter to create Firebase Storage adapter.

I tried using kreait/laravel-firebase package and I tried this code

```
Storage::extend('firebase', function ($app, $config) {
        $storageClient = new StorageClient([
            'projectId' => $config['project_id'],
            'keyFilePath' => $config['key_file'],
        ]);
        $bucket = $storageClient->bucket($config['bucket']);
        $adapter = new GoogleStorageAdapter($bucket, $config['path_prefix']);

        return new Filesystem($adapter);
    });
```

The problem with this example is that GoogleStorageAdapter class is part of superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage package and I can't install it since it is not compatible with Laravel 9 and Laravel 10 and I don't know what to use instead.